# what happens to this equation after change of variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, change-of-variable

I have the following equation $f$:

$$
f(\frac{1}{z}) = 1 + \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z(z+1)} + \frac{1}{z(z+1)(z+2)} + ...
$$

If I make a change of variable $\frac{1}{z}=k$, does this mean that the equation becomes ?

$$
f(k) = 1 + k + k(k+1) + k(k+1)(k+2) + ...
$$

If not, what should the form for $f(k)$ be?

Comment: Dude. Just take the expression (right-hand side of the first line) and write $\frac{1}{k}$ in the place of $z$ . What is the result that you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(k)=k+\frac 1 {\frac  1 k (\frac 1 k +1)}+\frac 1 {\frac  1 k (\frac 1 k +1)(\frac 1 k +2))}+...=k+\frac {k^{2}} {k+1}+\frac {k^{3}} {(k+1)(2k+1)}+...$.

The general term is $\frac {k^{n+1}} {(k+1)(2k+1)...(nk+1)}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

As you can check by yourself,

$$\frac1{z(z+1)(z+2)}=\frac1{\dfrac1k\left(\dfrac1k+1\right)\left(\dfrac1k+2\right)}=\frac{k^3}{(k+1)(2k+1)}.$$